# Как перевести цифры в двоичные

Tags: массивы

Методика быстрая нужна как переводить цифры в двоичные

Comment: Делаете массив, где индекс - десятичная цифирь, значение - её двоичное представление. И выбираете по цифре аки по индексу.

Comment: у вас есть какие то другие способы перевода в двоичные кроме деления на 2 ?

Answer (score 0):

Сделать словарь и сопоставить числам их двоичное представление, например:

```
{ 0: "0", ..., 3: "11", ..., 15: "1111" }
```

Далее после числа 15 будет перезапуск чисел с нуля с дописыванием единицы в начале и сохранением числа разрядов, т.е. число 16 = 10000.
Соответственно есть 2 варианта, либо сгенерировать словарь длиной до максимального требуемого числа и брать число по индексу, либо делить число на 15 и понимать, сколько необходимо разрядов, и по остатку смотреть (0-14) чему равны остальные разряды.